# Fetching data from Google Calendar into Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm very new to coding and I want to create my very own project, but I'm not sure how to start.

I want to create a program that will:

1. Grab the calendar event name from my Google calendar
2. Take only the relevant parts I need
3. Organize it into Excel
4. Print me the resulting graph from the given data.

So, to begin, are there any resources I might look at first? 
I did some searching, found [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java), but I don't quite understand what to do with that.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Get an IDE like visual studio code or eclipse to code. I recommend Visual Studio Code.

Become familiar with Java in the IDE:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_create-the-program

Then follow those Google instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to check out Visual Studio Code; however, I've mostly become accustomed to Sublime since that's what we use at school. Would Sublime suffice as an IDE for this project?

Comment: I don’t recommend it, but to each his own. My experience with Sublime is that it is more of a text editor than an IDE. Eclipse has been around for years, but the interface is quite bulky relative to Visual Studio Code. Visual Studio Code is a bit cleaner. It has several plugins for just about any language you can think of to debug your code.